# Bottom to Top Listboxes

Tags: c#, listbox

How would I load my Listbox from bottom to top? I haven't been able to find anything for c# about this.

I looked through the properties of Listbox but there isn't anything for item alignment.

Answer (score 1):

I use

```
listBox.Items.Insert(0, "hello world");
```

for logging where I want the most recent item at the top of the listbox